# Wordpress Jupiter Chrome CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, cross-browser, compatibility

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this issue... The jupiter theme is showing a white overlay on top of the full screen video in chrome but displays fine in firefox... I've looked through the css and can't seem to find any issues... but the strange thing is that when I open the inspector and delete the main container for the page section then hit command Z the white space dissappears and I can see the whole video... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link:
http://s579222454.onlinehome.us/about-us